# Counting repetive values in zipped list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I'm working on a short script which computes data from two zipped list, here is example of my raw data:

[image]

as you can see on the last (5th one) column I have two repetitions (value 65). What I need is a piece of code, that will automatically sum up values from 4th column for every repetition in 5th column.
So far I have written this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = pd.read_csv('/home/20181111.csv', header=None, sep=';',
                   usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], names=['Time', 'f1', 'p1', 'Intensity', 'Distance'])

distancelist = [[distance, intensity] for distance, intensity in zip(data['Distance'], data['Intensity'])]
```

And here I stuck, because I have no clue, how to sum up `intensity` value for every repetition in `distance`, any ideas?

Below is a piece of code, which sum up repetitions, but when lists are not zipped.

```
listofpoints = Counter(distancelist)

for k, v in listofpoints.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: `data.groupby('Distance').Intensity.sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @piRSquared suggested.

```
distance_df = pd.DataFrame(distancelist, columns = ["Distance", "Intensity"])
result = distance_df.groupby('Distance').Intensity.sum()
```

Comment: Solution by @piRSsquared works, although using yours I got `KeyError: Distance". Still thanks for solving that one for me :)

Comment: Sorry, @Hiddenguy forgot to add the column names, can you verify it works now?

Comment: now it works perfectly :) Btw. can I somehow take this values as a list or something?

Comment: Yes. You can do `result.tolist()`, and it should convert into a list.